# Connection pooling - closed connection issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, connection-pooling

Problems:

I have a web app that is getting battered. Everything is working but I get about two errors a day I can not explain. It could be the first user hitting the system because the error appears in the error log intermittently it occurred today around 7:30 am in servers time zone (same as the users).

I fixed an old issue by implicitly destroying the connection by way of the `using` statement as it only marks the connection as recyclable.

Error Log:

```
Message: 3df8d62a-6b47-479e-b5d2-b23e0db92d92 : System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid operation. The connection is closed.
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.GetOpenConnection()
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.get_ServerVersion()
 at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.get_IsServer2005()
 at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.InitializeProviderMode()
 at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
 at System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
 at System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
 at xxxxx.Resources.Data.LINQ.DistrictService.GetDistrict(Int32 districtID)
```

Related Code:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------        
        public Domain.Data.District GetDistrict(int districtID)
        {
            using (_dataContext = new DistrictDataDataContext(_systemService.GetCurrentSystem().WriteOnlyDatabase.ConnectionString))
            {
                Mapper.CreateMap<District, Domain.Data.District>();
                return (from s in _dataContext.Districts
                        where s.DistrictID == districtID
                        select Mapper.Map<District, Domain.Data.District>(s)).SingleOrDefault();
            }
        }
```

Note:

I think that this is a non-issue because the inherent behavior of the connection pooling might be firing a retry (this could just be information saying "hey we tried what you asked for but the connection was closed, we will now open one up it.") however, If this is the case, I do not get a confirmation of successful retry and I am not even sure would be expected. We have had no complaints and this cant be duplicated in house by our QA staff. I hope maybe someone else has come across this.